# Use an Excel chart object on Powerpoint slide

Tags: excel, vsto, powerpoint

I am creating a PowerPoint add-in for creating charts. I want to know if I can use a Excel chart instead of PowerPoint chart in my add-in since both the charts look same and have the same charting engine. If I can then what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

```
1. Create a chart in Excel and then use PasteSpecial to paste it in the PowerPoint slide 

2. Add an OLE object of Excel.Chart by using Shapes.AddOleObject method.
```

Both these methods have advantages and disadvantages. But this depends on what are you trying to do.